# Should I check Multicollinearity When There is An Inverse?

Tags: machine-learning, multicollinearity

At Machine Learning algorithms there are usually inversion process about matrices and sometimes Matlab throws error when Multicollinearity occurs.

**Should I check Multicollinearity(and how) everytime before I inverse a Matrix (and use pseudo inverse - pinv)**

Comment: Interesting question. I don't have a full answer, but you might look at the code in the R `perturb` package which slightly perturbs values. I think they do this only for statistical models, but a similar method could be used for inverses. If a slight change in the matrix yields a large change in the inverse, that would be a sign of collinearity

Comment: People who have done a lot of numerical analysis with matrices routinely compute their [condition numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) to check for potential instability in operations like inversion.

Comment: @whuber I had this issue when I was implementing LDA. When inversing matrix all element were Inf at Matlab and took I pseudo inverse of matrix. Is there anything wrong what I do?